# Throwing ZeroDivision Error Python

Tags: python

I am trying to throw an error in Python and I keep getting a Syntax Error

```
def dx(f, x):
    return abs(0-f(x))

def newtons_method(f, df, x0, e):
    try:
        delta = dx(f, x0)
        while delta > e:
            x0 = x0 - f(x0)/df(x0)
            delta = dx(f, x0)
        print('Root is at:', x0)
        print('f(x) at root is: ', f(x0

    except (ZeroDivisionError) as err:
        print(err)

def f(x):
    return x**2 - 1
    # return 6*x**5 -5*x**4 -4*x**3 +3*x**2

def df(x):
    return 2*x
    # return 30*x**4 -20*x**3 -12*x**2 +6*x

x0s = [-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1]

for x0 in x0s:
    newtons_method(f, df, x0, 1e-5)
```

And when I run it in the console this is what is printed:

```
(tensorflow) Dans-MacBook-Pro:research danhessler$ python newton.py 
  File "newton.py", line 17
    except (ZeroDivisionError) as err:
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have tried raising the error but that did not work either.

Comment: Look at the line above where the error is. Hint: count the number of brackets...

Comment: please use an ide such as sublime text . Syntax errors would be a lot simpler to spot

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you. Such a silly error.

Answer (score 1):

The except wasn't the problem it was the line above it.
I had:

```
print('f(x) at root is: ', f(x0
```

And Changed it to:

```
print('f(x) at root is: ', f(x0))
```

That fixed it.